# org.jetbrains:annotations doesn't work when running Maven tests manually

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently developing a Java 8 application in IntelliJ IDE. I came across [JetBrains annotations](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jetbrains%7Cannotations%7C15.0%7Cjar) and I started using them like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA(@NotNull ClassB classB, @NotNull ClassC classC) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and test file like this:

```
public class ClassATest {
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorNull1() {
        new ClassA(null, null);
    }
}
```

As long as I am running application/tests from IDE annotations work, but when I run e.g. `mvn tests` from command line, I get a lot of `NullPointerException` instead of expected `IllegalArgumentException` when testing `null` arguments. It seems the annotations are ignored.

I assume problem is somewhere in misconfiguration of `pom.xml` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.22</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>...</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong? Thank you.

Platform: GNU/Linux (Kubuntu 16.04)
Java: OpenJDK 1.8.0_121
Maven: 3.3.9

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you add maven plugin:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repository.jetbrains.com</id>
        <name>repository.jetbrains.com-all</name>
        <url>http://repository.jetbrains.com/all</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>notnull-instrumenter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>tests-instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```